# What is the most efficient/quickest way to loop through rows in VBA (excel)?

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I know VBA in Excel isn't the quickest of things - but I need the most efficient (i.e. quickest) way to loop through a large sample of rows.

Currently I have:

```
For Each c In Range("$A$2:$A$" & Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    ' do stuff
Next c
```

The 'do stuff' includes insert a row here and there (so I need to keep the dynamic lookup of the range.)

Any ideas (looking at 10,000 rows+)?

EDIT
I am already using

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

Comment: It has been nearly a decade since I worked with VBA in Excel, so I'm a little foggy. But, I thought there was a way to turn off updating the screen while doing large processes like this which tended to speed things up considerably. I may not be remembering it correctly, though.

Comment: 100% correct, I am using Application.ScreenUpdating = False and Application.Calculation = xlManual (will add to question)

Comment: You could try getting rid of the range by tracking any inserts you do yourself, but I tend to think there's not much optimization that could be done on the for loop construct itself. I could certainly be wrong about that, but you should benchmark how long it takes just to do the loop with nothing at all inside of it just to see if you could actually save a significant amount of time there or if you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I think you meant `xlManual` in your edit.

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` can also be a real performance booster if your code doesn't depend on Worksheet/Workbook events being triggered.

Comment: you forgot a `)` right before the `.row` at the end .  Fixed `For Each c In Range("$A$2:$A$" & Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)).row`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you are just looping through 10k rows in column A, then dump the row into a variant array and then loop through that.

You can then either add the elements to a new array (while adding rows when needed) and using Transpose() to put the array onto your range in one move, or you can use your iterator variable to track which row you are on and add rows that way.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim varray As Variant

varray = Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(varray, 1)
    ' do stuff to varray(i, 1)
Next
```

Here is an example of how you could add rows after evaluating each cell. This example just inserts a row after every row that has the word "foo" in column A. Not that the "+2" is added to the variable i during the insert since we are starting on A2. It would be +1 if we were starting our array with A1.

```
Sub test()

Dim varray As Variant
Dim i As Long

varray = Range("A2:A10").Value

'must step back or it'll be infinite loop
For i = UBound(varray, 1) To LBound(varray, 1) Step -1
    'do your logic and evaluation here
    If varray(i, 1) = "foo" Then
       'not how to offset the i variable 
       Range("A" & i + 2).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 loops are unnecessary sometimes. Dump the range into an array, do what you need to the array, then dump it back. A dynamic second array (using Redim) can help when you need to "add rows" to the original data.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm a big fan of redim on a second array myself :)

Comment: +1 on the variant array, and +1 on JPs comment to handle new rows

Comment: I really like the idea of new array, but I am hitting a snag. Example - Range(...).value returns an array such as a(10,10). Say I have a second array, Redim a2 as variant, if I want to insert a 'row', I would ReDim a2 to 10+1, but how do I copy a(1) to a2(1) when 'a' as an entire row - at the moment I have to loop through every value across a2(1, 1) = a(1, 1), a2(1, 2) = a(1, 2), etc because I can not extract just the row of the array

Comment: Chris, it's for that reason that I suggested that you just insert rows using the i variable (if you start from A2 and you need to add a row, you know that the new row should be i +1). Adding rows to a new array can be worth it, but the comlexity is a trade-off for sure. The idea is usually that you transfer elements from one array to the other, adding rows as you go.

Answer (score 21):

**EDIT**  Summary and reccomendations

Using a `for each cell in range` construct is not *in itself* slow.  What *is* slow is repeated access to Excel in the loop (be it reading or writing cell values, format etc, inserting/deleting rows etc).

What is too slow depends entierly on your needs.  A Sub that takes minutes to run might be OK if only used rarely, but another that takes 10s might be too slow if run frequently.

So, some general advice:

1. keep it simple at first.  If the result is too slow for your needs, then optimise
2. focus on optimisation of the content of the loop
3. don't just assume a loop is needed.  There are sometime alternatives
4. if you need to use cell values (a lot) inside the loop, load them into a variant array outside the loop.
5. a good way to avoid complexity with inserts is to loop the range from the bottom up
   (`for index = max to min step -1`)
6. if you can't do that and your 'insert a row here and there' is not too many, consider reloading the array after each insert
7. If you need to access cell properties other than `value`, you are stuck with cell references
8. To delete a number of rows consider building a range reference to a multi area range in the loop, then delete that range in one go after the loop

eg (not tested!)

```
Dim rngToDelete as range
for each rw in rng.rows
    if need to delete rw then

        if rngToDelete is nothing then
            set rngToDelete = rw
        else
            set rngToDelete = Union(rngToDelete, rw)
        end if

    endif
next
rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
```

**Original post**

Conventional wisdom says that looping through cells is *bad* and looping through a variant array is *good*.  I too have been an advocate of this for some time.  Your question got me thinking, so I did some short tests with suprising (to me anyway) results:

test data set: a simple list in cells `A1` .. `A1000000` (thats 1,000,000 rows)

Test case 1: loop an array

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim n As Long

T1 = GetTickCount
Set r = Range("$A$1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Cells
v = r
For n = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    'i = i + 1
    'i = r.Cells(n, 1).Value 'i + 1
Next
Debug.Print "Array Time = " & (GetTickCount - T1) / 1000#
Debug.Print "Array Count = " & Format(n, "#,###")
```

Result:

```
Array Time = 0.249 sec
Array Count = 1,000,001
```

Test Case 2: loop the range

```
T1 = GetTickCount
Set r = Range("$A$1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Cells
For Each c In r
Next c
Debug.Print "Range Time = " & (GetTickCount - T1) / 1000#
Debug.Print "Range Count = " & Format(r.Cells.Count, "#,###")
```

Result:

```
Range Time = 0.296 sec
Range Count = 1,000,000
```

So,looping an array *is* faster but only by 19% - much less than I expected.

Test 3: loop an array with a cell reference

```
T1 = GetTickCount
Set r = Range("$A$1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Cells
v = r
For n = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    i = r.Cells(n, 1).Value
Next
Debug.Print "Array Time = " & (GetTickCount - T1) / 1000# & " sec"
Debug.Print "Array Count = " & Format(i, "#,###")
```

Result:

```
Array Time = 5.897 sec
Array Count = 1,000,000
```

Test case 4: loop range with a cell reference

```
T1 = GetTickCount
Set r = Range("$A$1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Cells
For Each c In r
    i = c.Value
Next c
Debug.Print "Range Time = " & (GetTickCount - T1) / 1000# & " sec"
Debug.Print "Range Count = " & Format(r.Cells.Count, "#,###")
```

Result:

```
Range Time = 2.356 sec
Range Count = 1,000,000
```

So event with a single simple cell reference, the loop is an order of magnitude slower, and whats more, the range loop is twice as fast!

So, conclusion is **what matters most is what you do *inside the loop*, and if speed really matters, test all the options**

FWIW, tested on Excel 2010 32 bit, Win7 64 bit
All tests with

- `ScreenUpdating` off,
- `Calulation` manual,
- `Events` disabled.

Comment: You're missing the most important test - loop the varray with varray reference. There is no point in test 3 - why loop an array but make a call to excel for every element and ignore the contents of the array? I think you'll find looping the array and referencing its elements is substancially faster than looping a range and referencing the cells (make sure you test with data inside the cells you are testing (not empty cells)).

Comment: @Issun sorry, but you miss the point: the OP clearly states *The 'do stuff' includes insert a row here and there* so a reference to the sheet inside the loop is required.  The choice of instruction was deliberately trivial and not ment to be meaningful. If there is no need to reference the sheet inside the loop then using a zarray reference is the obvious answer and can (and did) go without saying.  The really interesting thing here is using a loop over the cells is *in itself* not a costly method.  What matters more is what you do inside the loop.

Comment: Simply assigning a variable tmp to equal the cell value, 1M longs too 2.234sec for range and 0.3428sec for array in my tests. Similar results for strings (about a third of a second longer for both methods).

Comment: Sorry, I am assuming that if the code will insert rows here and there, it needs to reference the cell values to determain where it needs to insert the rows (otherwise no reason at all to loop the range!). The actual insertion of the rows will take the same amount of time no matter which method, so I am not considering that.

Comment: +1 BTW, I do want to give you a +1 for well researched answer!

Comment: @Issun what about an empty loop (ie test 1, 2) does your test show different results to mine? And waht version of Excel are you using

Comment: Just wanted to add that test 3, what I meant was that you are *not* looping the array at all - you are simply referencing its lower and upper bounds to get 1 and 1000000 numbers to set up the loop.

Comment: I am using 2007 and I show same results for empty loops. The reason is that Excel doesn't go back and look at the Range stated in the "for" line of the code, therefore no calls to Excel are being made during the loop. You can see this behavior by looping a varray and notice that swapping 1 and 100000 for ubound(varray, 1) and ubound(varray, 2) will have no effect on the loop speed (becuase it only gets that number once and doesn't do ubound calls each time).

Comment: Makes sence and explains why the time for the two methods is similar.  But in doing these tests one thing I tried was inserting a row in the loop.  Caused an infinite loop (as the range kept expanding) so the `for` must be rechecking the range I think?

Comment: I think it stores the range in temp memory (in a variable we cannot see or access) that it goes back to. There's no other way to explain why calling ubound a million times is no slower than hard coding 1000000. That or the cost of calling excel to get the 'next cell' is extreamlly fast and well implemented (while a call to get a value is slow). :)

Comment: The reason the "range loop is twice as fast" compared to cycling through `n` in `r.Cells(n, 1)`, is that the `For Each` construct is intrinsically quicker for marching through collections, compared to looking up collection members via their index, which is slower.  Of course if you decide to call the latter "looping through a variant", then "looping through a variant" is bad, but that's not what it is; it is "looping through [a collection of] cells" via their index, which conventional wisdom accurately describes as slow.

Comment: An empty loop is a really bad way to test speed in general, since a loop will not be doing *nothing*. The time to for/foreach loop is practically nothing when each item in the range/collection/array are not being referenced. The moment you do, for each loops DESTROY the for loops, and varrays DESTROY calls to excel cells 8so much so that the fact that you are using for instead of for each is irrelevent)

Comment: This is one of the most epic answers I've seen since I've been on SO. I'm going to try a bit of both from Issun and Chris and see what eventuates. I will trial today and mark an accepted answer based on what works best

Comment: General advice #7 is incomplete. Each of the following range properties perform parallel assignment to an array:  `Value, Value2, Formula, FormulaLocal, FormulaR1C1, FormulaR1C1Local`

Comment: VBA is just like VB6 in this regard. It is smart when it comes to loops. Most of these tests are meaningless, and there is nothing surprising here at all. The compiler is optimized for loops that do nothing and does not handle them as you might expect. The 19% difference between doing nothing with the collection vs the array is because the collection is an object while the array is contiguous memory. An important fact that you left out is that writing to cells is an order of magnitude slower the reading from them.

Comment: @brettdj can you tell me what im doing wrong in here i try to use that logic but its not working for me , here is my code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686786/how-do-i-loop-through-one-million-rows-in-vba-fastest-ways-possible-and-ya-this

Comment: @brettdj http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706967/how-do-i-loop-through-using-instr-value-in-vba

Comment: @brettdj can you please take a look on my page

Answer (score 2):

For Each is much faster than for I=1 to X, for some reason. Just try to go through the same dictionary,

---

once with for each Dkey in dDict,

---

and once with for Dkey = lbound(dDict.keys) to ubound(dDict.keys)

=>You will notice a huge difference, even though you are going through the same construct.