# How to set a cell value = to whats looping?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have this code below.  How can I set a cell value to = whats looping through that value?

```
Sub Test2()
      ' Select cell A2, *first line of data*.
      Range("A2").Select
      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
         ' Insert your code here.
         ' Step down 1 row from present location.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
   End Sub
```

Comment: What cell do you want to set?  Your question needs some clarification.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's probably a better way to do it than looping through every ... single ... cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer will better look like a comment but it is too long to fit in a comment (and cannot be formatted properly).

### How to loop over a range

I advise you to have a look at [Chip Pearson page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm) about optimizing VBA, especially looping over range in VBA.

When you loop over range, you shoul use the `for each` statement as described in this example:

```
Dim WS as Worksheet
For Each WS In Worksheets
    MsgBox WS.Name
Next WS

Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    MsgBox Worksheets(i).Name
Next i
```

### Finding the last empty cell

Your code seems to try to find the last empty cell. You can do it easily with

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)
End With
```

You can find some more tips on [ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm) (even if they don't use `rows.count`)

### Avoiding Selects

Your code will be **very very slow** if you are trying to `Select` every cell in a loop.

You'd better use the **object model** of VBA.
For instance, if you only want to copy the *value* of a cell:

**Don't do**

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Paste
```

**Do**

```
Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Value
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw, congrats for your 3000+ :) (sorry, I missed the day when you've passed it)

Comment: Thanks - that means a lot coming from one of the users here I respect the most ^^ I was really happy to have passed that milestone :)

Comment: +1 but you should be recommending reading a range into an array. Also, the OP's goal is unclear and maybe looping isn't the best solution.

Comment: Thanks JP. As pointed out by Jean-François Corbett in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178161/what-is-the-most-efficient-quickest-way-to-loop-through-rows-in-vba-excel/8178637#comment10046400_8178637). It depends if you need to loop over the values (and then put the range in an array is the best solution) or if you need to change the cell and thus, looping over the collection is probably faster.

Comment: +1 and congrats to Issun on +3000, and Jmax for the imminent +6000. :)