# Split Date and String in Excel VBA

Tags: string, vba, date, excel, split

I'd need to get an amount of hours from data in the following format:

```
'166:05 hod:min'
```

The first number is the amount of hours, next after `':'` are minutes. The rest can be thrown away.

My idea was to split the first number, add the second number divided by `60 [166:05 -> 166,08]`, but I'm the very beginner of VBA and these things.

Comment: It sounds like the most logical proceeding. How do you expect to do it otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the Split command in VBA,

```
Dim splitTarget() As Variant
Dim splitMin() as Variant

splitTarget  = Split('166:05 hod:min', ":")
```

`splitTarget(0)` should return 166 and `splitTarget(1)` should return '05 hod'

```
splitMin = Split(splitTarget(0), " ")
```

SplitMin(0) will give you the 05

Comment: But this is not what the OP was proposing? I still don't get what this question was about! Also bear in mind that splitTarget(1) resulting from Split('166:05 hod:min', ":")  is not "05", but "05 hod"

Comment: Yeah you're right, splitTarget(1) = "05 hod". Another Split("05 hod", " ") should be done to retrieve the 05

Comment: Ok, therefore I need to clean this off the strings and apply it to a row (range of cells)? Any suggestion how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I removed it as answer by accident, I'm here for the first time. Yet I haven't figured out, how to make this work for the whole row. :]

Comment: Your question is just not clear.. maybe you have to bring on your whole problem, so we can see and find a solution. I can't figure out which row you are talking about.

Comment: Ok, now my problem is how to make this split work for a column (not a row... sorry!) of data in this format. Therefore I tried to write down a 'for each' cycle for the desired range of cells. Like this:    `For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        splitTarget = Split(rCell.Value, ":")
        splitTargetA = Split(splitTarget(0), " ")
        splitTargetB = Split(splitTarget(1), " ")
        rCell = splitTargetA(0) + (splitTargetB(0) / 60)
    Next rCell`

Comment: Check this link;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178161/what-is-the-most-efficient-quickest-way-to-loop-through-rows-in-vba-excel