# How to handle multiple IFTHEN queries across columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an allocation system, and whilst I've programmed `VBA` before I'm stuck this time!

I have data across five columns, the contents of which determine which staff member I allocate to them.

What I need to do is this:

```
If column E = "a", then put name "xx" in column A (of same row)
If column E = "b", then put name "yy" in column A (of same row)
If column E is blank, then move to next criteria....

If column D is "c" then put name "zz" in column A (of same row)
If column D is "d" then move to next criteria....

If column A is blank then put name "ww" in column A.
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817745/faster-way-to-loop-through-cells-with-if-elseif/19818371#19818371

Comment: or you can use `Worksheet_Change` event

Comment: Thanks Siddarth, but I got a little lost in that long formula, I suppose I'll have to trial and error it with my values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Allocate()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Range("E" & i) = "a" Then
            Range("A" & i) = "xx"
        ElseIf Range("E" & i) = "b" Then
            Range("A" & i) = "yy"
        End If

        If Range("D" & i) = "c" Then
            Range("A" & i) = "zz"
        End If

        If IsEmpty(Range("A" & i)) Then
            Range("A" & i) = "ww"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Note that

`If column E is blank, then move to next criteria....`

isn't included anywhere in the code, there is no point to implement this in the code because it literally does **nothing** :)

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the link under your question, you don't need loop for this.

If you were to use an Excel formula then you would use something like this

```
=IF(E1="a","xx",IF(E1="b","yy",IF(D1="c","zz","ww")))
```

Simply use that in the vba code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Formula = "=IF(E1=""a"",""xx"",IF(E1=""b"",""yy"",IF(D1=""c"",""zz"",""ww"")))"

        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**:

[image]