# My array loop is way really slow. Is there any way to improve this?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop, excel-2010

I am looping through each cell in my data to see if it matches specific string. If it matches, then it will terminate the loop and ask the end user to review the data. The thing is, this is still taking way too long if I have a lot of data. Is there a way to improve the speed of this? Thank you!

```
  Dim Keywords As Variant
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim iRange_Col As Integer
    Dim lRange_Row As Long
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim lRowCnt As Long
    Dim keyw As Variant
    Dim val As String
    Dim found As Boolean

    Keywords = Array(Chr(34), "'", ",")
    lastrow2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:BK" & lastrow2)
    iRange_Col = SearchRange.Columns.Count
    iRange_Row = SearchRange.Rows.Count
    ReDim vArray(1 To iRange_Row, 1 To iRange_Col)
    vArray = SearchRange

    For lRowCnt = 1 To iRange_Row
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("D16") = "Revised!" Or _
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("D15") = "Revised!" Or _
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("D17") = "Revised!" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    For lCnt = 1 To iRange_Col
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("D16") = "Revised!" Or _
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("D15") = "Revised!" Or _
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("D17") = "Revised!" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Application.StatusBar = lCnt
        val = vArray(lRowCnt, lCnt)

       For Each keyw In Keywords
           found = InStr(1, val, keyw) <> 0
           If (found) Then
               Exit For
           End If
       Next

    If found Then
        If keyw = "," Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("D15") = "Revised!"
        Else
            If keyw = Chr(24) Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("D17") = "Revised!"
            Else
                If keyw = keyw = "'" Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("D16") = "Revised!"
                End If
            End If
        End If


    End If


    Next lCnt
 Next lRowCnt
```

Comment: If you dump the range into a `Variant` array it will be much faster, see for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178161/what-is-the-most-efficient-quickest-way-to-loop-through-rows-in-vba-excel

Comment: Turning off the screen-updating with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` should improve it.

Comment: You have a typo in there: `Chr(34)` but then later you have `Chr(24)`   How much data do you have?

Comment: You seems to be exiting the routine as soon as you've found a single "problem" character.  Wouldn't you (and your end-users) be better-off if you highlight all "problem" cells ? Maybe set the cell font red if it contains one of the characters?

Comment: If you're interested in a fuller review of your code, this might be a good candidate for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah I noticed the typo too. Fixed that. Data could get as big as 100k. I would love to highlight all "problem" cell. But if that causes the code to run even slower, I would rather not.

Comment: @loannis: I tried changing searchrange into a variant instead. But the code crashes when i tried running it. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: @AndyG I did. It did run a little faster. but still pretty slow when it comes to large data set.

Comment: I would first change the name to something like `vSearchRange` and then do `vSearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:BK" & lastrow2).Value2`. No `ReDim` is necessary. Then instead of `SearchRange.Rows.Count` we need `Ubound(vSearchRange, 1)` and `SearchRange.Columns.Count` should become `Ubound(vSearchRange, 2)`. I would also store the values of `D16:D18` so that you do not have to poke the `Worksheet` object in each iteration.

Comment: I guess my point about listing all errors is that if I were *using* this code I'd not be very happy with continually having to run it just to find the single next problem and then run it yet again after that one was fixed. If you think it's already too slow, then just running it *once* seems like a better option. I guess it all depends on what you expect the "error rate" in the data will be....

Comment: You have another typo ,`Dim lRange_Row As Long`, and later you're referencing `iRange_Row = SearchRange.Rows.Count`.  That's why it's important to have `Option Explicit` at the top of every module.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that speeds things up is commenting out the `Application.StausBar` line.  In my case, processing 40,000 rows went from 2.5 minutes to just under 7 seconds.  Also, as Ted Williams suggested, this routine highlights ALL flagged cells in one shot.  Hope this is helpful.

```
Sub findHilite()

    Dim Keywords As Variant
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim lRowCnt As Long
    Dim keyw As Variant
    Dim val As String
    Dim lastrow2 As Long
    Dim rBld As Range

    Keywords = Array(Chr(34), "'", ",")
    lastrow2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:BK" & lastrow2)

    SearchRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    vArray = SearchRange

    For lRowCnt = 1 To SearchRange.Rows.Count 'rows loop
        For lCnt = 1 To SearchRange.Columns.Count 'columns loop
'            Application.StatusBar = lRowCnt 'display row count
            val = vArray(lRowCnt, lCnt)

            For Each keyw In Keywords
                If InStr(1, val, keyw) <> 0 Then
    '               build range consisting of flagged cells
                    If Not rBld Is Nothing Then
                        Set rBld = Union(rBld, SearchRange(lRowCnt, lCnt))
                    Else
                        Set rBld = SearchRange(lRowCnt, lCnt)
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

        Next lCnt
    DoEvents
    Next lRowCnt
    On Error Resume Next
    rBld.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'hilite flagged cells in one step, saves time
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```