# Excel VBA: Efficient way to compare dates in large loops

Tags: vba, excel

### **Program Description**

I'm trying to do Sub for making raports from many files. Every file consists from rows ordered by date, and there is no fixed number of these. Some got only 300, others over 10 000. Every row is divided in modules, with describes some problems appereance, also there is sum of all columns in every module.
Raport should present how many problems from certain module has appeared over time set by the user, in certain files also checked by the user.

### **Problem**

My Sub works, but im not sure if I'm doing it correctly. For one file operation is taking around 6 seconds , but for all it's sometimes nearly 2 minutes (5000 loops per file in the largest loop), with is quite long. I'm almost sure there are more efficient ways to do the job. I guess, the main problem is the way I'm checking date in every row - it's also the longest loop. After some reading:

- http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VBALoops.htm
- [What is the most efficient/quickest way to loop through rows in VBA (excel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178161/what-is-the-most-efficient-quickest-way-to-loop-through-rows-in-vba-excel)

I don't really understand how to apply here f.e. *Filter* or *Find* functions, also I was trying with *Arrays* and *Foreach*, but time executions were nearly the same (sometimes better, sometimes not). Also I think that many *If's* and nested loops may slow *Sub* down. Maybe there are some *parallel loops* or *thread useage* in Excel VBA to speed it up? I think Excel always uses only 25% of proccessor. Also my attempt to give the user a little chance to configure the loop scope (*Number1* and *Number2* in **Code**) reduces time from 2 minutes to 30 seconds with good set ups, but DataBase files needs to be checked and cleaned from time to time, so it's not the best solution.

I'm just starting programming and it's my first big project, so I'm aware of bad quality of code, I'm hoping that You could guide me a little to make this turtle faster. Sorry for long post.

### Code

It's quite large, so I deleted some not-so-important peace (it's described).

```
Sub CopyInfo()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Sheets("Silnik").Select

   'Cleaning cells for raporting (they need to be empty)
    Call Czyść

   'Variable for storing data value
    Dim Value

   'Timer - to see how long it takes
    Dim t As Single
    t = Timer

   'Variables for opening and closing scope of checking data (editable by the user)
    Dim Data1, Data2
    Data1 = Cells(3, 9).Value
    Data2 = Cells(4, 9).Value

   'Position of cells in raport can change (P - row, P2 - column), easy edit
    Dim Postion, Position2
    Position = 9
    Position2 = 13

   'With row should I start looking (N1)? How many rows should I look for dates (N2)?
   'Get search scope values from sheet (these cells are editable by the user)
    Dim Number1, Number2
    Number1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Silnik").Cells(2, 28)
    Number2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Silnik").Cells(3, 28)

   'With files should I test? Do I need to test all of them, or just few (LiniaStany)
   'Check state of the file (user can edit with file hes testing)
   'Also - get names of the files (LiniaNazwy) - they can change in time
    Dim LiniaStany(16), LiniaNazwy(16)
    For i = 0 To 15
       LiniaStany(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Silnik").Cells(2 + i, 22)
       LiniaNazwy(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Silnik").Cells(2 + i, 21)
    Next

   'Variables for workbooks
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim vFile As Variant
   'Set current workbook (to this file)
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook


   'Core
   'i means currently opened file
    For i = 0 To 15
       'Check if file should be tested, if yes, then set FilePath and open
       If (LiniaStany(i) > 0) Then
          vFile = "C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\kontrol " & LiniaNazwy(i) & " M.xlsm"
          Workbooks.Open vFile
         'Set DataBase workbook
          Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
         'Number is currently tested row in chosen file
          For Number = Number1 To Number2
             Value = wb2.Worksheets("Baza").Cells(6 + Number, 1)
             'Check if date is in the scope
             If (Value >= Data1) And (Value <= Data2) Then
                'Get information about SUM of problems in "module1"
                 wb.Sheets("Wyniki").Cells(Position - 1, 4 + i * 3) = wb.Sheets("Wyniki").Cells(Position - 1, 4 + i * 3) + wb2.Worksheets("Baza").Cells(6 + Number, 80)
                 'Check if problems>0, if yes, get more informations
                  If (wb2.Worksheets("Baza").Cells(6 + Number, 80).Value > 0) Then
                      For WK = 0 To 17
                          wb.Sheets("Wyniki").Cells(Position + WK, 4 + i * 3).Value = wb.Sheets("Wyniki").Cells(Position + WK, 4 + i * 3).Value + wb2.Worksheets("Baza").Cells(6 + Number, Position2 + WK).Value
                      Next WK
                  End If
                 'Get information about SUM of problems in "module2"
                  wb.Sheets("Wyniki").Cells(Position + 18, 4 + i * 3) = wb.Sheets("Wyniki").Cells(Position + 18, 4 + i * 3) + wb2.Worksheets("Baza").Cells(6 + Number, 82)
                  If (wb2.Worksheets("Baza").Cells(6 + Number, 82).Value > 0) Then
                      For ZAP = 0 To 9
                         'ZAP - Detale
                          wb.Sheets("Wyniki").Cells(Position + ZAP + 18, 4 + i * 3).Value = wb.Sheets("Wyniki").Cells(Position + ZAP + 18, 4 + i * 3).Value + wb2.Worksheets("Baza").Cells(6 + Number, Position2 + ZAP + 17).Value
                      Next ZAP
                  End If
                  'Some more ifs (7)..., same way, cut out
                  '...
                  '...
            End If
            'See if row is empty or not - if yes, stop the main loop
            If (Value < 1) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Number
        'Close DataBase workbook, go to another one
        wb2.Close False
    End If
Next

Sheets("Raport").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = screenUpdateState
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = eventsState

Beep
MsgBox "Operation time: " & Timer - t & " seconds."

End Sub
```

Comment: The code looks pretty good. 2 minutes is reasonable for 15 files, no?  VBA does not support threading.  So, what is your actual **problem**?

Comment: Well, if it is, then it's all OK. As I said, that was my first bigger project and I was curious if there are other, faster ways to do this. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out after some time, there is NO NEED to compare dates **like this** in loop. **Never.** Excel provides filters, which can be used to reduce range of cells only to these, which meet certain criteria, described in filter. The easiest way to do this, is to **turn on macro recorder** and set filter on cells range. Code should look like this (after injecting dateStart and dateEnd):

```
With Sheet1

            .AutoFilterMode = False

            .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter

            .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=dateStart", _

             Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=dateEnd"

    End With
```

But, if we loop through range with this filter, we still got same results. To make if efficient, we need to use only cells that are visible (filtered). To achieve this we can use **special cells**:

```
Set rng = Range("A2:D50")

For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'Do something on cells in date range
Next cl
```

After replacing outer loop with this method, its possible to filter out other options, from different columns (adding different filters with different fields and criteria). In this way, there is no need to use **for loops at all**. With this methods its possible to reduce time **from minutes to few seconds.**