# Extracting from numerous Excel files into one data table or file

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have over 100 .xlsx files. Each file has two sheets. The first sheet (always called sts) usually has 15-20 thousand rows, with a column called "Code". The second sheet (always called cps) has about 85k rows, also with the same Code column.

I need to extract all the rows for a specific code from sheet sts, into a table/sheet, and all the rows for a specific code from sheet cps into a second table/sheet. I need to do this for all the files.

I have experimented with two approaches

1) Use Excel VBA to open each file, use an autofilter to copy the code rows needed into a master workbook for collation. Using the following code to get the files from a pre-defined starting directory and drill down `Public Sub SearchFiles()`.

```vb
Public Sub SearchFiles()

'Macro to start the file extraction by drilling down from the mydir path specified
Dim code As String
Dim time1 As Double
Dim time2 As Double

Range("a1").Value = InputBox("Please type code to extract", code)
time1 = Timer

myFileSearch _
myDir:="C:\Data\Dashboard\2014\New Files Excel Loop", _
FileNameLike:="Reporting", _
FileTypeLike:=".xlsx", _
SearchSubFol:=True, _
myCounter:=0

time2 = Timer
MsgBox time2 - time1 & "seconds"

End Sub


Private Sub myFileSearch(myDir As String, FileNameLike As String, FileTypeLike As String, _
  SearchSubFol As Boolean, myCounter As Long)
Dim fso As Object, myFolder As Object, myFile As Object
Dim Rowcount As Long
Dim rowcount2 As Long
Dim masterbook As Workbook
Set masterbook = ThisWorkbook
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim commodity As String

code = Range("a1").Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each myFile In fso.GetFolder(myDir).Files
    Workbooks.Open (myDir & "\" & myFile.Name)
    myCounter = myCounter + 1
    ReDim Preserve myList(1 To myCounter)
    myList(myCounter) = myDir & "\" & myFile.Name

    ''loop to pull out all code rows in your directories into new file
    Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Worksheets(1).Range("d2").Activate
    Rowcount = Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
    Rows(1).AutoFilter
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=code, Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("a" & Rowcount)

    'filter out the code data
    Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Worksheets(2).Activate
    Range("d2").Activate
    rowcount2 = Workbooks(1).Sheets(2).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
    Rows(1).AutoFilter
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=code, Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
      Destination:=Workbooks(1).Sheets(2).Range("a" & Rowcount)

    Workbooks(myFile.Name).Close savechanges:=False
Next

If SearchSubFol Then
    For Each myFolder In fso.GetFolder(myDir).SubFolders
        myFileSearch myDir & "\" & myFolder.Name, FileNameLike, FileTypeLike, True, myCounter
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Opening up each workbook takes 5-10 seconds and the entire process is very slow (and with bugs at the moment).

2) Import everything into two Access tables and then clear down just for the code rows I desire. This is slower than the Excel approach because of the amount of rows.

```vb
Sub pulloop()

DoCmd.RunSQL "delete * from sts"
DoCmd.RunSQL "delete * from cps"

strSql = "PathMap"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)

With rs

    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst

        While (Not .EOF)
            importfile = rs.Fields("Path")

            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acimport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Sts", importfile, True, "Sts!A:G"

           DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acimport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "CPs", importfile, True, "CPs!A:Q"
            'Debug.Print rs.Fields("Path")
            .MoveNext
        Wend

    End If

    .Close

End With

End Sub
```

I adapted this to try and use AcLink, but I am struggling with the implementation of it. Would it be possible to use aclink rather than acimport to query out the required code rows of each file when it comes into Access, and if so would this perhaps be a faster way?

Comment: Question better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Maybe this question has someful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178161/what-is-the-most-efficient-quickest-way-to-loop-through-rows-in-vba-excel

Comment: How long does the actual data manipulation take compared to the 5-10 second file opening overhead? There are some improvements that could be made (removing the `Activates` etc). Perhaps a new route such as saving the `xlsx` files as `csv` files and using PowerShell (not too hard to learn) to manipulate the `csv` files would make a difference for a repeatable task

Comment: The opening of the files is the first time consumptive task, which I would like to get around by somehow getting the data from a closed workbook. The other consumptive task is copy pasting the autofilter data. I have read that putting the data into an array and setting the range of the workbook that is taking in the data equal to that array, is much faster than copy paste.  I wouldnt mind learning how to use powershell but I the files need to stay in their original format as they are on a shared drive and new ones come in everyday, and I cannot maintain a seperate csv library of them.

Comment: You don't say why you're having problems with acLink. I think linking to the spreadsheets, then running your queries on this linked tables may be your best bet.

Comment: My problem with AClink is merely that I haven't used it before to query from the temporary table it creates. How do I actually run the sql against it ? Say I want to query out all rows from the STSLink table created from the ACLINK, where field "code" is equal to "C". I want those put into the actual access database table entitled STS. Please does anyone know what the line of code would be fore this ?

Comment: How about merging all 100 sheets into one Access table? create Two tables, and import all sts into one table, and all cps into another table. now run your normal query. (Migration from excel to ACcess)

You can link 100 files, again you are not using the database performance if you have 100 different files.

Comment: HI I found that importing all 100 sheets into access was nearly 10 mmillion rows and took quite a long time to import. I need this to be adhoc. Cutting down to just the specific datarows I want brings it down to a couple million but I found that either creating a new superfile via loop extraction or a large access import both takes 10 or more minutes. Any faster suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the issues in your second option, which I would tend to favor, is that you are importing ALL the rows from the Excel file. Try using the Excel object model to define a named range on both sheets and then use docmd.transferspreadsheet in the loop.  You will need to alter the column refs for the other sheet.  HTH.

Code to find the actual rows used, define a named range and import into Access:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application     
Dim xlWkb As Excel.Workbook       
Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet 
Dim lngLastRow as Long
Dim myImportRange as Range
dim strRangeName as String
set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible=False 'make it go faster
set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("PATH")
set xlWS = xlWB.Sheets("sts")
lngLastRow=xlWS.Range("A" & xlWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set myImportRange = xlWS.Range("A1:G" & lnglastrow)
strRangeName="myData_2014MMDD"  'or any name that makes sense to you
myImportRange.Name=strRangeName
xlWB.Save
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, <Dest Table>, xlWb.FullName, True, strRangeName
xlApp.DisplayAlerts=False 'suppress save changes prompts
xlWB.Close False
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a third approach querying workbooks directly in an append SQL query:

```vb
With rs
   .MoveLast
   .MoveFirst

   While (Not .EOF)                
      importfile = rs.Fields("Path")
      Debug.Print importfile

      sql = "INSERT INTO sts " _
          & " SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR = Yes;Database=" & importfile & "].[Sts$A:G]"

       CurrentDb.Execute sql, dbFailOnError

      .MoveNext
   Wend        

   .Close    
End With
```