# VBA Sub to Remove Blanks From Row Improvements

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a sub to remove the blank entries in a row without shifting the cells around but it seems unnecessarily clunky and I'd like to get some advice on how to improve it.

```
Public Sub removeBlankEntriesFromRow(inputRow As Range, pasteLocation As String)
    'Removes blank entries from inputRow and pastes the result into a row starting at cell pasteLocation

    Dim oldArray, newArray, tempArray
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    'dump range into temp array
    tempArray = inputRow.Value
    'redim the 1d array
    ReDim oldArray(1 To UBound(tempArray, 2))
    'convert from 2d to 1d
    For i = 1 To UBound(oldArray, 1)
        oldArray(i) = tempArray(1, i)
    Next
    'redim the newArray
    ReDim newArray(LBound(oldArray) To UBound(oldArray))
    'for each not blank in oldarray, fill into newArray
    For i = LBound(oldArray) To UBound(oldArray)
        If oldArray(i) <> "" Then
            j = j + 1
            newArray(j) = oldArray(i)
        End If
    Next
    'Catch Error
    If j <> 0 Then
        'redim the newarray to the correct size.
        ReDim Preserve newArray(LBound(oldArray) To j)
        'clear the old row
        inputRow.ClearContents
        'paste the array into a row starting at pasteLocation
        Range(pasteLocation).Resize(1, j - LBound(newArray) + 1) = (newArray)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to consider [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) for this kind of question.

Comment: Yes, here you are wrong, since your code is working and it is done the typical VBA way, not that much optimization necessary

Comment: @hexereisoftware I [really hate that attitude toward vba development](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/the-professional-vba-developer/). There is certainly room for improvement of this code. Professionals should act like it. I applaud this person for recognizing it could be improved and asking for help doing so.

Comment: @RubberDuck i develop VBA myself, and my comment was not supposed to transfer any negative message towards VBA development. I was just pointing out, that there is no error in the code, and that it is better placed in code review as you mentioned, because here i would expect more questions where things are not working at all or have errors. So from that perspective the code is fine and it surely can be optimized - but not here :)

Comment: I'm sorry about the misunderstanding @hexereisoftware. Happy to know we're on the same page.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. I'll post over in code review as well. I'm not familiar with what the "typical VBA way" is since I'm new to programming and vba in general.

@Mat'sMug I don't understand most of your comment ("implicitly passed ByRef", "multiple declarations in the same instruction", "variables implicitly declared as Variant", "variable declared but never assigned or referred to". I've bookmarked your linked Rubberduck site since it looks like it might be helpful.

I see the actualPosition variable was declared but never assigned a value. I forgot to remove it when I updated.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/86192/9357).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my take on the task you describe:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Public Sub removeBlankEntriesFromRow(inputRow As Range, pasteLocation As String)
    'Removes blank entries from inputRow and pastes the result into a row starting at cell pasteLocation
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim new_array As String(inputRow.Cells.Count - WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(inputRow))

    For Each c In inputRow
        If c.Value <> vbNullString Then
            inputRow(i) = c.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    Range(pasteLocation).Resize(1, i - 1) = (new_array)
End Sub
```

You'll notice that it is quite different, and while it may be slightly slower than your solution, because it is using a `for each`-loop instead of looping through an array, if my reading of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8178637/4497791) is correct, it shouldn't matter all that much unless the input-range is very large.

It is significantly shorter, as you see, and *I* find it easier to read - that may just be familiarity with this syntax as opposed to yours though. Unfortunately I'm not on my work-computer atm. to test it out, but I think it should do what you want.

If your main objective is to improve the performance of the code, I think that looking into what settings you may turn off while the code is running will have more effect than exactly what kind of loop and variable assignment you use. I have found [this blog](http://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/) to be a good introduction to some concepts to bear in mind while coding in VBA.

I hope you have found my take on your problem an interesting comparison to your own solution, which as others have mentioned should work just fine!

Comment: Couple points: I'd prefer `vbNullString` over `""` because `vbNullString` is a null string pointer while `""` is just an empty string - try `Debug.Print StrPtr(""), StrPtr(vbNullString)`, you'll see that `""` is actually allocated a space in memory. Also I'd avoid declaring multiple variables in the same instruction, for readability.

Comment: Incorporated your suggestions to the answer, @Mat'sMug

Comment: #FunFacts: the [codereview.se] cross-post generated 17 votes. The only upvotes I'm seeing on this page are all mine. If you liked posting this answer, you'll enjoy CR :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Heh, Excel-VBA isn't a popular tag here, I suspect :) Might head over to code review and see what they've got there.

Answer (score 2):

If I am to understand you want to delete blanks and pull the data left on any given row?

I would do it by converting the array to a string joined with pipe |, clean any double pipes out (loop this until there are no doubles left) then push it back to an array across the row:

Here is my code:

```
Sub TestRemoveBlanks()
    Call RemoveBlanks(Range("A1"))
End Sub

Sub RemoveBlanks(Target As Range)
    Dim MyString As String
    MyString = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range(Target.Row & ":" & Target.Row))), "|")
    Do Until Len(MyString) = Len(Clean(MyString))
        MyString = Clean(MyString)
    Loop
    Rows(Target.Row).ClearContents
    Target.Resize(1, Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, "|", ""))).Formula = Split(MyString, "|")
End Sub

Function Clean(MyStr As String)
    Clean = Replace(MyStr, "||", "|")
End Function
```

I put a sub to test in there for you.

If you have pipes in your data, substitute it with something else in my code.