# How do I concatenate all strings in two different columns?

Tags: vba, excel

Without starting to mess about with extra columns, etc., is there a better way to concatenate the strings from two columns than using a double for-loop as outlined in the code below?

```
Sub test(endra_celle As Range)
  Dim plass_i_årsakslister, c1 As Range, c2 As Range
  Dim i As Long, endra_rad As Long
  Dim ovnsnummer() As String

  endra_rad = endra_celle.Row

  Set plass_i_årsakslister = Range(Årsakslister.Range("C1"), _
                    Årsakslister.Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft)).Find(What:= _
                    registrering.Range("C" & endra_rad).Value, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

  If Not plass_i_årsakslister Is Nothing Then
    With plass_i_årsakslister
      i = 0
      For Each c1 In Range(.Offset(2, 1), .Offset(1048575, 1).End(xlUp))
        For Each c2 In Range(.Offset(2, 3), .Offset(1048575, 3).End(xlUp))
          ReDim Preserve ovnsnummer(i)
          ovnsnummer(i) = CStr(c1) & CStr(c2)
          i = i + 1
        Next
      Next
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

To elaborate; each of the cells in the first column should be combined with each of the cells in the second, and all the combinations should be stored in an array (or other collection).

Comment: It's the only way. It will be slow, though, so to make it faster you can dump the 2 ranges into 2 arrays, and then loop on the arrays instead of the cells. It will make it much faster. But the logic remains the same.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, I'll go for that, although according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8178637/4497791) the difference in time between using `For` vs `For Each` should be fairly small in this case? Having googled SQL-queries in VBA a bit, after getting the answer from Dan below, I considered trying something [like this](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/68905-SQL-array-using-VBA-%28VBA-Excel-2003%29?p=383199&viewfull=1#post383199) instead, but it just looks like a lot of effort for small reward with the size of the datasets I currently have.

Comment: It's not a difference between for and for each. It's a different between reading the sheet vs reading the array. Think of it like reading library books. You can either go to the library, take 20 books home, and read them and bring them back. Or you can go to the library, bring a book home, read it, bring it back, take another one, bring it home, read it, take it back, go back to the library....20 times. Reading from the sheet takes a lot of time. For small datasets it wouldn't matter so much.

Comment: @DavidG Obviously. It must have been too early for me when I wrote that :-P

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Dim a
a = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Evaluate("A1:A9&B1:B9"))
```

Just replace `A1:A9` and `B1:B9` with your column ranges.

This works because `Evaluate()` properly detects this as an array formula and operates on each cell in turn. By default, however, it will return a two-dimensional array (with the column always equal to 1). `Transpose()` swaps the rows and columns so that the *rows* are always 1 and, therefore, Excel can return a 1D array.

Comment: Trying this [seems to give me an array full of errors](http://i.imgur.com/cC0is4d.png), except for the first four values. It also seems to hold far fewer values than it should.

Comment: Your ranges are two different sizes. `D3:D6` but `F3:F29`. What should happen with `F7:F29`?

Comment: I know. Each of those cells should also be combined with each of the cells in D3:D6.

Comment: This answer isn't going to work for you then. I didn't realize that's what your code was doing.

Comment: That's a shame =/ I elaborated a bit in my question to make it more clear what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

There could be another way, to test if this works with the number of line...

- Create a name range on each of your ranges, for example FirstCol on column A and SecondCol on column B
- Save your workbook (In my example Book1.xlsx in c:\temp)
- Open another workbook, select cell A1 of first worksheet and choose "Data / From Other Sources / From Microsoft Query
- Choose "Databases / Excel Files" as data source
- Select the book you have just saved above
- The "Query Wizard / Choose column" should display and show your 2 data ranges firstCol and secondCol.
- Put them in the "Columns in your query" by selecting each and clicking on the > button
- Press next. An error message about joining tables will appear. Just ignore it and press OK.
- Once done, it should open a window with the "Microsoft Query" and some data.
- Click on the little button SQL and a window with the SQL query should appear
- In the SQL Statement, replace the coma between the 2 columns by an & (To concatenate the values of col1 and col2) and add the WHERE condition like in the sample code afterwards. You may have to adjust depending on how you named your columns and range.

  ```
  SELECT FirstCol.Col1 & SecondCol.Col2
  FROM `C:\temp\Book1.xlsx`.FirstCol     FirstCol, 
       `C:\temp\Book1.xlsx`.SecondCol    SecondCol
  WHERE (FirstCol.Col1>'') AND (SecondCol.Col2>'')
  ```

BY doing this joining of table without a proper joining condition, you will perform what is know in SQL as a "Cartesian Product" of the table, meaning that each line of the first table will be combined with each line of the second. If you have 50 rows in FirstCol and 10 in secondCol, you will finish with a 500 lines in result...

Of course, if you have a chance to use a proper database engine, it could be much better, for example using .csv files that you load as external tables in a ORACLE DB
However, this works for me but needs to be tested with your dataset as the response time could be quite bad if you have a large number of rows...

Hope that helps

Sample result[image]