# How do i loop through using instr value in vba

Tags: vba, excel

How do i loop through one million rows in vba to find the instr numbers then trying to copy it to different sheet. I have a two different worksheet, one of them holding one million strings and the one 150. And im looping through to finding instr then pasting into another sheets.My code is working slow also how do i make it faster.

[image][image][image]

```
Sub zym()
  Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long, lastrowx As Long, i As Long, ii As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet, wb2 As Workbook
  Dim b As String, ws3 As Worksheet, ym As Long, lastrowy As Long, iii As Long
  Dim j As Integer

     Dim data As Variant
     Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
     Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
     Set ws3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")
     j = 1
    Dim sheet1array As Variant, sheet2array As Variant
     T1 = GetTickCount
    lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowx = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   ReDim sheet1array(1 To lastrow)
   ReDim sheet2array(1 To lastrowx)
    data = Range("A1:Z1000000").Value

  For i = LBound(sheet1array, 1) To UBound(sheet1array, 1)
     b = "-" & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & "-"
      For ii = LBound(sheet2array, 1) To UBound(sheet2array, 1)

        If data(i, ii) = InStr(1, ws2.Cells(ii, 1), b) Then
           ws3.Range("A" & j) = ws2.Range("A" & ii)
          j = j + 1
        End If
        Next ii
      Next i
    Debug.Print "Array Time = " & (GetTickCount - T1) / 1000#
    Debug.Print "Array Count = " & Format(n, "#,###")

    End Sub
```

Comment: @brettdj Here is the new one

Comment: How long does it take like this?

Comment: How about just using .Find for finding the strings...?

Comment: This is not clear: `If data(i, ii) = InStr(1, ws2.Cells(ii, 1), b) Then...` - how can `data(i, ii)` be equal with the position of the string in `ws2.Cells(ii, 1), b)`. Can you post a few sample strings from sheet1, a few from sheet2, and what you expect on sheet3. Also is data in sheet1 and sheet2 all in one column?

Comment: What are you doing with `sheet1array` and `sheet2array` ? You dimension them, but never use them except to read the lbound and ubound from them: you may as well just have used `lastrow` and `lastrowx` for that purpose...   Also this `data = Range("A1:Z1000000").Value` doesn't specify which sheet is being read from, so it's hard to follow the rest of the process.  If this relates to any of your previous questions then adding links to those would help.

Comment: @paulbica i did uploaded 3 images for 3 sheets and what i am trying to do find instr for ex 123 then copy the value whole number xret-123-njnjj
into sheet 3 thats the logic... but its slow plus my code is duplicating value too

Comment: Can a value from sheet1 match more than one value on sheet2?  Are all values on sheet2 formatted exactly as shown (only one number per value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested with 0.5M entries on sheet1 and 150 on sheet2:

```
Sub tym()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim b, c As Range, rngNums As Range, rngText As Range
    Dim dNums, dText, rN As Long, rT As Long, t, m



    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set c = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    Set rngNums = ws1.Range(ws1.Range("A1"), ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    dNums = rngNums.Value
    Set rngText = ws2.Range(ws2.Range("A1"), ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    dText = rngText.Value

    t = Timer

    'Method1: use if only one possible match
    ' (if any number from sheet1 can only appear once on sheet2)
    ' and sheet2 values are all of format 'text-number-text'
    For rT = 1 To UBound(dText, 1)
        b = CLng(Split(dText(rT, 1), "-")(1))
        m = Application.Match(b, rngNums, 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            c.Value = dText(rT, 1)
            Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next rT
    Debug.Print "Method 1", Timer - t
    t = Timer

    'Method2: use this if conditions above are not met...
    For rN = 1 To UBound(dNums, 1)
        b = "*-" & dNums(rN, 1) & "-*"
        For rT = 1 To UBound(dText, 1)
            If InStr(1, b, dText(rT, 1)) > 0 Then
                c.Value = dText(rT, 1)
                Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next rT
    Next rN

    Debug.Print "Method 2", Timer - t

End Sub
```

- Method1: ~0.5 sec
- Method2: ~17 sec

Answer (score 0):

the find method of a range is faster: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Maybey you could give this a try?

Answer (score 0):

This code expects to find headers for column A on both sheets(1 and 2)

- It removes duplicates from column A on Sheet1
- It Autofilters Sheet2 for each item on Sheet1
- Copies visible rows from Sheet2 to Sheet3

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub findValues()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, vr As Range
    Dim ur1 As Range, ur2 As Range, ur3 As Range, thisRow As Long
    Dim i As Byte, ur As Range, itms As Variant, itm As Variant

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1"): Set ur1 = ws1.UsedRange
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2"): Set ur2 = ws2.UsedRange
    Set ws3 = Worksheets("Sheet3"): Set ur3 = ws3.UsedRange

    ur1.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    itms = ur1.Columns(1)
    If ws2.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then ur2.AutoFilter
    Set ur = ur2.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ur2.Rows.Count - 1, ur2.Columns.Count)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each itm In itms
        If i > 0 Then
            ur2.Columns(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & itm & "*"
            Set vr = ur2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If vr.Count > ur2.Columns.Count Then
                ur.Copy ur3.Cells(ur3.Rows.Count + 1, ur2.Column)
                Set ur3 = ws3.UsedRange
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
    ws3.Cells(1).EntireRow.Delete
    ur2.AutoFilter
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: i don't know why did you filter it and i ran the code, its not working or copying i just want a simple code something find the match once find the match on sheet2 just take the values and paste into sheet3