# Run-time error '1004' when looping through a large sample of rows

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, runtime-error

In order to achieve the most efficient way to loop through a large sample of rows, I created the following code in Sheet3 inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8178335/3397819):

```
Sub Testing_Data()
Dim k As Long, S2 As Worksheet, VArray

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set S2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
VArray = Range("A:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value

For k = 2 To UBound(VArray, 1)
    S2.Cells(k, "B") = VArray(k, 1) / 100
    S2.Cells(k, "C") = VArray(k, 1) * S2.Cells(k, "B")
Next
End Sub
```

After running the code, the **Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error** occurred. How to fix it?

Comment: Which line returns the error?  At the point the error occurs; what are the values of your variables?

Comment: @destination-data It doesn't point to any lines.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 When there is an issue with your code, you can run through it step by step using the F8 key, this way you can see which lines are able to execute and at what point the error is thrown.

Comment: @OliverCarr Thanks for the tips. Let me try your answer in VBA editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After stepping through your code the error is on the `VArray =` line, two things here:

1. `Range("A:A"...` should instead be `Range("A"...` as you are specifying a row and not selecting the entire column from top to bottom of the entire sheet.
2. A `Range` of multiple succeeding cells can be referenced by using 
   `Range(FirstCell, LastCell)`. Your code selects only the bottom cell and so by adding `"A1",` at the start of your range reference it will select all the cells you need.

---

```
Sub Testing_Data()
Dim S2 As Worksheet, VArray() As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set S2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    VArray = Range("A1", "A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

For k = 2 To UBound(VArray)
    S2.Cells(k, "B") = VArray(k, 1) / 100
    S2.Cells(k, "C") = VArray(k, 1) * S2.Cells(k, "B")
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: **Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference**

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 I have updated my answer with a couple additional adjustments to your code.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 Glad to hear it, I have updated my answer to provide further explanation.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 You should accept the answer, not just vote on it. :)

Comment: @Tom I know the drill. I'm a user in other SE network, too. I make a habit of  waiting a few moment before accepting the answer. Thanks for reminding, though. :)

Comment: The incorrect range constructor is the cause of the error; what you (OP) really meant is not far away: `VArray = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value`. Of course, all enclosed in the `S2` With-Block, which makes a significant performance difference.

Comment: @user1016274 I did try your answer, but it still occurs the Run-time error '1004'. See [this capture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LQOpZ.png).

Comment: You still used the "Range(A:A..." instead of "Range(A1:A...".

Comment: @user1016274 I used the "Range(A:A..." because it was written in your answer. Why didn't you correct your answer when I said in comment "the error still occurred"?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, just too many places to edit in. I'll try to improve.

Answer (score 1):

user1016274 is right you need to either add S2 for your range and cells

```
VArray = S2.Range("A:A" & S2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

or follow his advice:

```
With S2
    VArray = .Range("A:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With
```

which is very useful. it saves time and space when you have multiple statments.

The other mistake is in your `Range`.You have to define 2 cells separated by a comma, here you define the column A and the cell in last row separated by `&`. Try this:

```
VArray = Range(S2.Cells(1, 1), S2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
```

**EDIT:**
When I run this, it works fine for me:

```
Sub Testing_Data()
Dim k As Long, S2 As Worksheet, VArray

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set S2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

VArray = Range(S2.Cells(1, 1), S2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value

For k = 2 To UBound(VArray, 1)
    S2.Cells(k, "B") = VArray(k, 1) / 100
    S2.Cells(k, "C") = VArray(k, 1) * S2.Cells(k, "B")
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Using your code or user1016274's, **The Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error occurred** still occurs.

Comment: It works for me. I just edited my answer with the whole code. let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I swear the error still occurs using your updated answer

Comment: That's strange... i cannot find why it doesn't work for you. maybe you should declare your array properly as variant: VArray() As Variant. i'm sorry I could not solve this.

Comment: Even if I omit the part `() As Variant` in @OliverCarr's answer, his code still works fine. No need to apologise

Answer (score 0):

```
VArray = Range("A:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

is NOT referencing `Sheet2` but the currently displayed sheet. Use

```
With S2
    VArray = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With
```

Notice the change from "A:A" to "A**1**:A". The `Range` object needs a starting cell and an ending cell reference separated by a colon.

You should put the following statements into the `With` block as well, for performance reasons. This way, the reference to the sheet would only be searched for once, not multiple times.

Comment: missed an extra `.` maybe needed in front of the `rows.count`?

Comment: This has the same problem as the question: `Range("A:A100")` (for example) is not a valid range...

Comment: I know. Please see my comments with Oliver's post. Basically, a `1` is missing, `Range(A1:A100)` would be valid.

Comment: If you know your answer has an error then maybe correct the error?