# Find Areas in a row by excluding cells/ranges less than a certain value

Tags: vba, excel, areas

I am trying to find Areas in each row, looping one row at a time, which are separated by values that are less than a certain value, say, < 3. Then find the largest Area that has count of cells >= 6 and set it to a range object. Then i want to find the corresponding start and end dates of this range from the 1st row.

I donot want to loop the cells in each row and check cell's value if it falls below 3. Is there a quick and efficient way to achieve this using VBA without looping the cells in each row?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could try to transpose your data and then use filter.

Comment: hi @EganWolf, thanks for your suggestion, but it will not be workable to transpose and filter in my scenario.  i am looping through the rows and there are other columns before the date column. It is a large crosstab table.

Comment: Depending on how large your table is, looping through the cells shouldn't be too slow. See this for further discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178161/what-is-the-most-efficient-quickest-way-to-loop-through-rows-in-vba-excel

Comment: @tom I can do the loopings, but I want to make the code very slim it concise. The idea is to find an innovative way to quickly extract range Areas from rows that meet a certain criteria.