# Looping through each cell in a range, replacing value and adding a comment faster

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a code that loops through a range, looks for a value and if there's a match it changes the cell value and adds a comment. I am doing this for 4 different values so it's taking a while for the code to run. Is there anyway to make this faster?

I've looked into putting the row into an array but I'm not sure how it could be applied to my code: [What is the most efficient/quickest way to loop through rows in VBA (excel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178161/what-is-the-most-efficient-quickest-way-to-loop-through-rows-in-vba-excel/42781175)

```
Sub Replace()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

   For Each Cell In Range("F9:F" & Rows.Count)

   If (Cell.Value = "Aide-général (REMPLAÇANT)") Then
    Cell.Value = "Aide-général"
    Cell.AddComment "REMPLAÇANT"
    End If

    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In Range("F9:F" & Rows.Count)

   If (Cell.Value = "Cariste") Then
    Cell.Value = "Cariste (8300 / 3700)"
    Cell.AddComment "Cariste"
    End If

    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In Range("F9:F" & Rows.Count)

   If (Cell.Value = "Cariste (3700)") Then
    Cell.Value = "Cariste (8300 / 3700)"
    Cell.AddComment "Cariste (3700)"
    End If

    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In Range("F9:F" & Rows.Count)

    If (Cell.Value = "OP Break&Lunch Torréfaction (3700)") Then
    Cell.Value = "Torréfaction (3700)"
    Cell.AddComment "Break&Lunch"
    End If

    Next Cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Just use `Range.Find`?

Comment: use range.find / range.findnext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the if functions with a select case and only have one 
for loop so the code only loops through the cells once

```
Sub Replace()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each Cell In Range("F9:F" & Rows.Count)
        Select Case Cell.Value
            Case Is = "Aide-général (REMPLAÇANT)"
                Cell.Value = "Aide-général"
                Cell.AddComment "REMPLAÇANT"
            Case Is = "Cariste"
                Cell.Value = "Cariste (8300 / 3700)"
                Cell.AddComment "Cariste"
            Case Is = "Cariste (3700)"
                Cell.Value = "Cariste (8300 / 3700)"
                Cell.AddComment "Cariste (3700)"
            Case Is = "OP Break&Lunch Torréfaction (3700)"
                Cell.Value = "Torréfaction (3700)"
                Cell.AddComment "Break&Lunch"
            Case Else

            End Select

    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Guys sorry I changed the if functions with a select case and only have one for loop so the code only loops through the cells once